# I need help hiding an element when hovering over another non child/parent/sibling element

Tags: javascript, web

I'm a beginner when it comes to javascript and I'm trying to write a script to hide a class when I hover over another class. I've written this piece of code however it isn't working as I'd like it to.Could someone give me some pointers as to why this code isn't working and some advice on how to get it to achieve the results I'm looking for.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    "use strict";
     document.getElementsByClassName('nav-bar').onmouseover = function(){

            document.getElementsByClassName('site-title').style.display="none";
    };

    document.getElementsByClassName('nav-bar').onmouseout = function(){

            document.getElementsByClassName('site-title').style.display="inline";
    };

});
```

edit

@Jonas

```
$(document).ready( function () {
"use strict";
 document.getElementsByClassName('nav-bar').forEach(function(el){el.onmouseover = function(){
document.getElementsByClassName('site-title').forEach(function(el){el.style.display="none";}
    );
  };
}
);

document.getElementsByClassName('nav-bar').forEach(function(el){el.onmouseout = function(){
document.getElementsByClassName('site-title').forEach(function(el){el.style.display="inline";});
};});

});
```

this is your adapted code. I'm not sure why it isn't working have i done it correctly?

edit 2

```
<body>
<Header>

<div class="navigation-wrap"> 
    <div class="logo"><img src="../images/logo2.jpg" alt="Lewis Banks Logo" title="Lewis Banks & Sons Ltd"></div>

    <div class="navigation">
        <nav class="nav-menu">

            <ul class="clearfix" >
              <li class="nav-button"><a class="nav-bar" href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li class="nav-button">
                <a id="product-button">Products</a>






                <ul id="product-list">
                    <li class="menu-dropdown2"><a href="../AC-Products.html" title="Centrifugal Switches"> AC</a> 
                        <ul id="AC-sublist">

                            <li class="dropdown-content"><a href="../CSW1-Switch.html">CSW1 Switch (15mm)<a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="dropdown-content"><a href="../CSW2-Switch.html">CSW2 Switch (20mm)<a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="dropdown-content"><a href="../CSW10-Switch.html">CSW10 Switch (30mm)<a>
                            </li>



                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-dropdown2"><a href="../DC-Products.html" >DC</a>
                        <ul id="DC-sublist">
                                <li class="dropdown-content"><a href="../Cartridge-Brush-Holders.html">Cartridge Brush Holders<a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="dropdown-content"><a href="../Brush-Holder-Caps.html">Brush Holder Caps</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="dropdown-content"><a href="../Extruded-Brush-Holders.html">Extruded Brush Holders</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="dropdown-content"><a href="../Pressed-Brass-Brush-Holders.html">Pressed Brass Brush Holders</a></li>


                                <li class="dropdown-content"><a     href="../Aluminium-Brush-Rockers.html">Aluminium Brush Rockers</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="dropdown-content"><a href="../Pressed-Brass-Brush-Rockers.html">Pressed Brass Brush Rockers</a></li>


                                <li class="dropdown-content"><a href="../Tachometer-Brush-Rockers.html">Tachometer Brush Rocker</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="dropdown-content"><a href="../Carbon-Brushes.html">Carbon Brushes</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="dropdown-content"><a href="../Constant-Force-Springs.html">Constant Force Springs</a>
                                </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>



            </li>

                <li class="nav-button"><a class="nav-bar"  href="../Applications.html">Applications</a></li>
                <li class="nav-button"><a class="nav-bar" href="../Old-and-New.html">Old & New</a></li>
                <li class="nav-button"><a class="nav-bar" href="../About-Us.html">About Us</a></li>


            </ul>





        </nav>



    </div>


</div>      




</Header>


<div class="site-title">
        <h1>Lewis Banks & Sons</h1>
        <h3><q>Labor Omnibus Unus</q></h3>
        <h4><i>Company motto since 1916</i></h4>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my html code, I apologize in advanced for the confusing state it is in this is the first website i've ever tried to to make and I've had to do a lot of trial and error and other acts of desperation when i came unstuck.

I have a top menu bar which has submenu's. I managed to do that using CSS.

The problem i have is as i hover over the sub-menus they overlap with the site title which makes the page look ugly. I don't want to move the site titel down so instead i'd like to remove it whenever you hover over the initial menu buttons. I want to to do this whilst maintaining the page structre (ie there's whitespace where the tite was).

Comment: Now that you have your javascript and html you could go one step further and put your javascript/css/html into a code snippet so people can see exactly what you are getting. https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using jQuery. Why not use jQuery selectors and methods to achieve your goal. It is easier to read and understand. Take a look at the following pages for more information:

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/
- https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Try this for example:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $(document).on('mouseover', '.nav-bar', function() {
        jQuery('.site-title').css('display', 'none');
    });
    $(document).on('mouseout', '.nav-bar', function() {
        jQuery('.site-title').css('display', 'inline-block');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

GetElementsByClassName returns a HTMLCollection. You need to loopover, and add to each:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('nav-bar').forEach(function(el){el.onmouseover = function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('site-title').forEach(function(el){el.style.display="none";});
};});
```

Comment: this code didn't work either i think it has something to do with '=>'

Comment: @SylvesterPeter WHY??

Comment: it said i required esversion 6

Comment: @SylvesterPeter may update your browser... (and dont use IE)

Comment: maybe i'm doing it incorrectly. I'm using the latest version of chrome but I still don't see anything. I've probably inserted your code incorrectly. Should i use it as it is or do i need to replace bits of my code with it?

Comment: @SylvesterPeter i didnt use the whole code, you have to replace your codes with mys...

Comment: by the way if the el=> still doesnt work in your browser replace it with function(el){...

Answer (score 0):

Like Dais mentioned in his answer, it looks like you are using jQuery so why not use the built in jQuery mouse events. Either that or you copied your code from somewhere and didn't realize that $ is a shortcut for jQuery and for your javascript to work you need to include jQuery. To include jQuery you need a statment similar to below in your html. This will include jQuery from google's content delivery network (CDN). There are other CDN's available including ones directly from jQuery.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Below is a working example using jQuery events and selectors.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
  $('#site-title').mouseover( function() {
    $('#site-title').hide(500);
  });

  $('#nav-bar').mouseleave( function() {
    $('#site-title').show(500);
  });
});
```

```css
#site-title {
  position:absolute;
  background:red;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}

#nav-bar {
  position:absolute;
  background:green;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav-bar">I am the nav bar
  <button>Nav1</button>
  <button>Nav2</button>
  <button>Nav3</button>
</nav>
<header id="site-title">I am the site title</header>
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I've included jquery in my html head tag  and adapted both yours and @Dais code to fit my own however it still isnt showing any signs of working.
  
the nav bar class doesn't actually refer to the entire bar but instead individual buttons, hence why i made it into a class i've now since changed it to nav-buttons to prevent confusion.

I should probably change site-title to an id however. The problem with using a header tag is that have 3 parts to the title all styled differently so it my site-title div acts like a container.

Comment: @SylvesterPeter I updated my code snippet to include buttons on the nav bar. Like you said, you can handle the events based on containers, and not individual components. You may want to have all of your site title html inside of a header element. It will behave pretty much the same as a div, but it communicates intent a lot better. Also wrapping your nav components in a nav element communicates intent better along with having some usability features built in to most browsers.

Comment: i've added a snippet of my html code so you can better understand what i'm trying to do would you suggest i nest the nav elements inside an li element or would it be better i ditch the li elements all together.

Comment: @SylvesterPeter I would suggest reading articles on web developement, specifically HTML5 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5 the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) is a good resource for all things web. I would say that nav elements inside an li element is not typical, but I don't know what you are trying to achieve exactly. Typically ul is for bulletted lists and not buttons. Also going through some tutorials could be beneficial https://learn.jquery.com/